# cannot reload the fullcalendar div after an ajax post click

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, fullcalendar

Im bulding a calendar via [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io).

im made an ajax button just will get the events from another php page.

the ajax button works fine and i am able to get the json with events and i get a nice month calendar display(on my first clicl on the ajax button).

my only problem is that: when i click the seconed time on the ajax button, the calendar do not reload/republish/render.. and im stuck with the first calendar (which is irelevent for me anyore).

anybody knows what is the problem and what can i do in order to republish a new calendar on every click on the ajax button?

here is the code:

```
<form id="my-form-id" method="post" action="Calendar_form3.php"> Year:
    <INPUT NAME="gregorian_year" SIZE=4 MAXLENGTH=4 value="2016">(1-6000) Latitude:
    <INPUT NAME="latitude" value="40.7127"> Longitude:
    <INPUT NAME="longitude" value="-74.0059"> <button id="ajax-button" type="button">Ajax button</button> </form>
<script>
    function displayCalendar() {
        var target = document.getElementById("main");
        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("my-form-id"));
        console.log(formData);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('post', 'JewishCalendar_form3.php', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            console.log('readyState: ' + xhr.readyState);
            if (xhr.readyState == 2) {
                target.innerHTML = 'Loading...';
            }
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                var Month_details_for_display = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                //var Month_details_for_display= JSON.parse(Month_details_for_display2);
                target.innerHTML = "funciton will start working...";
                displayCalendar222(Month_details_for_display);
            }
        }
        xhr.send(formData);
    }

    function displayCalendar222(Month_details_for_display) {
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
        var Events_In_Json = Month_details_for_display['EventsInSameStractureForAll'];
        var json_backgrundColor = Month_details_for_display['Big_Calendar_cell_background_color'];
        var json_iconstring = Month_details_for_display['iconString'];
        var DefaulteDateForFullCalendarISO8601 = Month_details_for_display['fullMonthDetails']['DefaulteDateForFullCalendarISO8601'];
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'next'
            },
            events: Events_In_Json,
            fixedWeekCount: false,
            defaultDate: DefaulteDateForFullCalendarISO8601,
            dayRender: function(date, cell) {
                var cellDate = date.format('D');
                if (!cell.hasClass('fc-other-month')) {
                    //if this if is true that means that the day belongs to the current relevent month (and not the prev \ next month)
                    cell.css('background-color', json_backgrundColor[cellDate]);
                    //from here: cheking which icons to show
                    if (json_iconstring[cellDate].includes('HAV')) {
                        cell.prepend('<img src=\' icons/havdala2.png \'>');
                    }
                    if (json_iconstring[cellDate].includes('Mod')) {
                        cell.prepend('<img src=\' icons/israel.png \'>');
                    }
                    if (json_iconstring[cellDate].includes('Jewish')) {
                        cell.prepend('<img src=\' icons/jewish.png \'>');
                    }
                    if (json_iconstring[cellDate].includes('PAR')) {
                        cell.prepend('<img src=\' icons/parasha.png \'>');
                    }
                    if (json_iconstring[cellDate].includes('CL')) {
                        cell.prepend('<img src=\' icons/cl.png \'>');
                    }
                    if (json_iconstring[cellDate].includes('Pub')) {
                        if (json_iconstring[cellDate].includes('USA')) {
                            cell.prepend('<img src=\' icons/usa.png \'>');
                        } else if (json_iconstring[cellDate].includes('UK')) {
                            cell.prepend('<img src=\' icons/uk.png \'>');
                        } else if (json_iconstring[cellDate].includes('CA')) {
                            cell.prepend('<img src=\' icons/canada.png \'>');
                        } else if (json_iconstring[cellDate].includes('AUS')) {
                            cell.prepend('<img src=\' icons/australia.png \'>');
                        } else if (json_iconstring[cellDate].includes('FR')) {
                            cell.prepend('<img src=\' icons/france.png \'>');
                        }
                    }
                    //until here:: cheking which icons to show
                } else {
                    //this days belongs to the prev \ next months. so we give them opacity)        
                    cell.css('background-color', '#ffffff');
                }
            },
        });
    }
    var button = document.getElementById("ajax-button");
    button.addEventListener("click", displayCalendar);
</script>
<div id='main'> result here </div>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd time you click on the button, you should call something like :

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
```

or completely destroy the calender before rendering it again, something like :

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy')
              .empty()
              .fullCalendar({
                 //...
              });
```

See

- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/render/
- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/destroy/

Comment: thanks for the answer. Where exactly should I locate this line? i tried putting it at the start \ end of the displayCalendar222 function and this is not working for me.

Comment: No you should run it only if the calendar is already initialized. You have to update the data using the API and call render. Otherwise you can destroy the calendar and render it completely.